# Javascript display/calculate past 3 months

Tags: javascript, date

I have a function that works out the past 3 months and displays the name by using an array.

I've just realised that when the new year comes round, for January, February & March, it won't be able to get the correct month.

I want to be able to do this without having to add in a hack (which is the only way I've seen to do this)

```
function getMonths()
    {
        var today = new Date();             
        var month = 0;
        var currMonth = month-3;

        var monthArray = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June",
                "July","August","September","October","November","December");

        var menuMonths = new Array();
        var count = 4;
        var buffer = 10;

        while(count >0)
        {           
            var month = monthArray[currMonth];
            alert(currMonth);
            menuMonths.push(month);

            currMonth = currMonth +1;
            count = count -1;
        }       
        return menuMonths;
    }
```

Comment: You are mentioned current month as '0' so that what you need to acheive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little addition to your while-loop will ensure that `currMonth` is always a valid index of your `monthArray`:

```
 while(count >0)
    {           
        if (currMonth < 0)
            currMonth += 12;
        if (currMonth >=12 )
            currMonth -= 12;

        var month = monthArray[currMonth];
        menuMonths.push(month);

        currMonth = currMonth +1;
        count = count -1;
    }
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RWhN4/
This is a bit hackish, but it should do what you want.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Bakudan, care to elaborate how this 'does absolutely nothing'?

Comment: @kalyfe first why you are declaring a date? You don't use it. Your solution is made to show only one answer. It will not change and will not be accurate let's say in three months. It will still show the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Modulus is your friend. Try:

```
function getMonths()
{
    var today = new Date();             
    var month = 1;

    var monthArray = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June",
            "July","August","September","October","November","December");

    var menuMonths = new Array();

    for(var count = 3; count >= 0; count--)
        menuMonths.push(monthArray[((12 + month - count) % 12)]);

    return menuMonths;
}

alert(getMonths());
```

Answer (score 0):

To figure out which month was 3 months ago you could do the following:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 3);
var monthIndex = d.getMonth() //(0-11)
```

Let standard javascript methods do the calculations for you.

Here is your function updated to use the javascript methods to do the calculations for you:

```
function getMonths() {
    var date = new Date();

    //subttract 3 months
    date.setMonth(0 - 3);

    var monthArray = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

    var menuMonths = new Array();
    var count = 4;
    var buffer = 10;

    while (count > 0) {
        var month = monthArray[date.getMonth()];

        alert(month);

        menuMonths.push(month);

        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);

        count -= 1;
    }
    return menuMonths;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function lastMonths(count,month,order) {
    var arr = [];
    //defaults
    month = typeof month !== 'undefined' ? month : new Date().getMonth();
    count = typeof count !== 'undefined' ? count : 3;
    order = typeof order !== 'undefined' ? order : "asc";

    while (count-- > 0) {
        month = (--month < 0) ? 11 : month;
        arr.push(["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"][month]);
    }
    return ( order === "asc" ) ? arr.reverse() : arr;
}
```

the function has defaults for the number of months to show, the start month, and the order
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u5p7S/)

Comment: This doesn't work.  It will repeatedly spit out December if say you're in January.  You should instead mod it

Comment: @Nader, thanks. You were right, the assignment of the new value to the month was wrong. It fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to what you guys did, but I did it for the [Trailing Twelve Months](http://www.crimson-cardinal.com/writings/technology/96-javascript-getting-the-trailing-twelve-months)  basically, in it's form format I used the following code:

```
$(".monthly_usage").val('');
    var monthArray = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
    var today = new Date();

    var month = today.getMonth();
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    var output = "Enter Trailing Twelve Months Usage<br/><center><table border=1 cellpadding=10 cellspacing=0><thead><th>Month - Year</th><th>Usage</th></thead><tbody>";
    for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        output += "<tr><td>" + monthArray[today.getMonth()] + " " + year + "</td><td><input type=text class=monthly_usage name=usage[]></td></tr>";
        var month = today.setMonth(today.getMonth() - 1);
        var year = today.getFullYear(); 
    }
    output += "</tbody></table>"+
    "<button id=submit_ttm>Submit Monthly Usage</button></center>";
    return output;
```